# Angular 2 Material MdSnackBar no Provider

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2, snackbar

I want a simple Snackbar popping up on the click of a button. But I always get the error:

> ERROR Error: No provider for MdSnackBar!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207

```
import {MdSnackBar} from '@angular/material';
constructor(public snackBar: MdSnackBar){
        this.snackBar.open('hello')
    }
```

Comment: have you add `MaterialModule` to your `import array`?

Comment: Did you import the `MdSnackBarModule`?

Comment: Early Morning here in Germany... thanks guys

Comment: @Pengyy Note that from `beta.3`, `MaterialModule` is depreceated and it is strongly recommended to create your own material module, as stated [here](https://material2-docs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/getting-started#step-3-import-the-component-modules) and [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#materialmodule).

Comment: @Edric thanks for pointing me out about this, bro. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Import MdSnackBarModule` then add `MdSnackBarModule` inside your imports in the **app.module.ts** file

Comment: Please note, this answer is no longer supported if your version is higher than "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.11",

Answer (score 11):

If you have version   "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12" or higher, you should import `MatSnackBarModule`

```
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material';

// Use a more specific import if you're using "@angular/material": "8.0.0" and higher
// import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

...

@NgModule({
      imports: [
            ...
            MatSnackBarModule
          ],
    ...
```